# Is it possible to skip column in CASE WHEN postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a query :

```
SELECT o.version, o.text, o.id 
case when language=1 
then o.language else [SKIP LANGUAGE COLUMN] end as language  
FROM books AS o
```

Is it possible to skip column `language` if `language!=1`? 
so if language=1 I'd like to get:
version|textt|id|language

otherwise:
version|textt|id|   (without language column)

Comment: `else null end`?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: So you want the column not to appear in your result set?

Comment: I editrd the question. yes I want the column not to appear

Comment: The case expression will always return something, either a defined value (e.g. o.language), or the _null_ value. A SELECT returns a fixed number of columns, it will never return more or less columns for different rows.

Comment: You cannot have a result that has a different number of columns in each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is it possible to skip column in CASE WHEN postgres?"

If by "Skip" you mean have the query project different number of columns in the result set, like @a_horse_with_no_name commented, NO.

You can assign null (or other value) in your else expression.

```
case when language=1 then o.language else null end as language
```

Or just leave the else out if you want nulls

```
case when language=1 then o.language end as language
```

If you must have different number of columns projected, you will need to execute two separate queries.